# bluetooth network traffic monitoring

Tags: pi-3b+, bluetooth

Is there anything that I can use to monitor my Bluetooth traffic just like the resource monitor in windows? I encounter nethogs in raspi but it only monitors wifi network. I want to know the B/sec of sent and received packets of Bluetooth.

Comment: *"I encounter htop in raspi but it only monitors wifi network."* -> Htop does not do this, so to prevent any confusion I have removed that from your question.

Comment: What I meant is nethogs. Sorry